# npm fails saying "The build tools for VS2010 cannot be found"

Tags: msbuild, npm, node-gyp, hubot

I'm trying to install Hubot on my local machine. Going well so far until I have encountered this error. The Error is pretty clear:

> Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "/m" switch.

However I am running the Hubot Initialization command `Yo Hubot`. And I am not able to use the **/m** switch. Any suggestions or advice on what I should do?

[image: Error Screen]

Comment: If the image is where you got the 'error' from then I suggest you have another read of the command line output. The error I see is that you are trying to build a solution with only VS2012 installed but the solution being made with VS2010. The errors states that you need the VS2010 build tools installed in order to build the given solution. So following the error message you can either install VS2010 or you can upgrade the solution to VS2012.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Enabling parallel build will not solve you problem, that one is just an informative message. The real problem is you don't have the Visual Studio version that was used to create one of the components Hubot needs.

Try this: `npm config set msvs_version 2012` (or 2013 if you have that one).

Comment: Yes, exactly! I have Visual Studio 2015 so I entered `npm config set msvs_version 2015` in my terminal as you mentioned and now my npm installs are running through VS 2015.. yay!